# Can nattable group by functionality be used to sort?

Tags: java, swt, nattable

So i am thinking about Nattable for a project, it looks excellent, but one of my requirement is to have a good configurable sort on multiple columns with a clear display of what is happening, having see the group example, this is a great bit of functionality:

[image: grouping functionality]

Where you can drag columns in to a bar that then groups the data by those values, this is what I would like for sorting, ie I don't want the tree expansion, or new rows added, I just want the table sorted in the order that  I have dragged the columns. I am trying to work out if this is going to be possible in nattable because the sorting examples for multiple columns are lacklustre compared to this grouping bar, so can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Sorting multiple columns in NatTable works if the `ISortModel` supports it.

The [_509_SortHeaderLayerExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_500_Layers/_509_SortHeaderLayerExample.java) has a custom `ISortModel` that does not evaluate the `accumulate` parameter. The [_602_GlazedListsSortingExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_600_GlazedLists/_602_GlazedListsSortingExample.java) uses the `GlazedListsSortModel` that supports sorting by multiple columns.

Using the `DefaultSortConfiguration` sorting by multiple columns works if SHIFT + ALT are pressed while clicking on the column header. Using the `SingleClickSortConfiguration` only the ALT key is pressed while clicking on the column header.

With a good understanding of the NatTable mechanisms it is possible to implement a sorting similar to the grouping UI. You need the grouping header and implement that it should sort instead of group. It is not supported out of the box.